# Toggle in-app GPS UISwitch, when the user toggles the app's location services

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location, uiswitch

The idea is to toggle the in-app GPS switch when the user toggles the app's location services from the Settings screen.

This is my Model

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager!,didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
switch status{
case .NotDetermined:
    println("Not Determined!")
    break
case .AuthorizedAlways:                            // It is being authorized always. If this is a security breach or causes
    println("Authorized Always!")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("GpsOn", object: nil)
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()   // Starts Updating Location in terms of latitude, longitude
    break
case .Denied:
    println("Denied!")
    break
default:
    println("Unhandled authorization status error")
    break
}
```

}

And the ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.initMenuWithTitle("Settings")
        settingsArray = ["Filters","Notification","GPS"]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("toggleGps:"), name: "gpsOn", object: self)

    }

func toggleGps(object:AnyObject){
        println("gps on")
    }
```

Comment: Good idea. What have you tried?

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried doing using the notification center but seems vain, having trouble figuring out when i should be listening to the change in the location settings.

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManager` might be what you're looking for:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: Thats pretty much what i've done in my model, posted the notification, added the observer in the view controller's viewDidLoad

Comment: So what else do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry if i am being vague here, i need to toggle the in-app gps switch when the user toggles the app's location services from the phone's settings screen.